# Change the Anti-Aliase value based on the font through script

Tags: javascript, photoshop

I have one requirement to change the Anti-Aliase value based on the font through script.
On that ArtLayer there are mixed of fonts used. But my requirement is to change the particular content which is applied the particular font.

Here i need to change all the content which is applied the "Courier New Regular" font.
Please check and help me to our from this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fQFP.png)

Thanks
Asuvath

Answer (score 1):

It's not obvious, but you can change the antialiasing type, regardless of font with the script listener.

If you then turn that code into a function you can change the the text anti-aliasing. (see below)

Just remember it only works if the active layer is a text layer.

```
// call the function with
//change_text_antialiasing("AnSt") // Strong
change_text_antialiasing("AnSm") // Smooth


function change_text_antialiasing(aatype)
{
  if (aatype == undefined ) aatype = "AnSm" //Smooth
  // "Anno" // None
  // "Annt" // Sharp
  // "AnCr" // Crisp
  // "AnSt" // Strong
  // "AnSm" // Smooth

  // =======================================================
  var idsetd = charIDToTypeID( "setd" );
  var desc38 = new ActionDescriptor();
  var idnull = charIDToTypeID( "null" );
  var ref4 = new ActionReference();
  var idPrpr = charIDToTypeID( "Prpr" );
  var idAntA = charIDToTypeID( "AntA" );
  ref4.putProperty( idPrpr, idAntA );
  var idTxLr = charIDToTypeID( "TxLr" );
  var idOrdn = charIDToTypeID( "Ordn" );
  var idTrgt = charIDToTypeID( "Trgt" );
  ref4.putEnumerated( idTxLr, idOrdn, idTrgt );
  desc38.putReference( idnull, ref4 );
  var idT = charIDToTypeID( "T   " );
  var idAnnt = charIDToTypeID( "Annt" );
  var idAnAA = charIDToTypeID( aatype ); // antialias type
  desc38.putEnumerated( idT, idAnnt, idAnAA );
  executeAction( idsetd, desc38, DialogModes.NO );
}
```